# How to call a c++ member function from gcc inline arm7 assembly

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, arm

I have the following piece of code that works on x86, and I need to convert it to gcc/arm7 inline assembly.

It seems replacing the stack would be a simple matter of moving the stack pointer into `r15` instead of `esp`, but I can't figure out how I would call the function, or get the actual variables into the arm assembly code.

```
Object *c;

unsigned long _stack = (unsigned long)c->stack + 65535;
void (Object::*_run)() = &Object::_run;

__asm
{
    mov ecx, _this // store pointer to this Object
    mov edx, _run  // store address of _run() function
    mov esp, stack // replace stack pointer with Object's internal stack
    call edx       // call the _run() function
}
```

**edit:**

so far, I have this:

```
unsigned long _stack = (unsigned long)c->stack + 65535;
void (Object::*_run)() = &Object::_run;

asm volatile("mov %[__this], %r0\n\t"
             "mov %[__run], %r5\n\t"
             "mov %[__stack], %%sp\n\t"
             "blx %r5\n\t"
             : /* no output operands */
             : [__stack] "r" (_stack), 
               [__this] "r" (_this), 
               [__run] "r" (_run)
             : /* no clobbers */);
```

Q: in x86 asm, using thiscall calling convention, the "this" pointer goes in ecx.
Where does it go in arm?

**edit:**

A: [`For C++, an implicit this parameter is passed as an extra argument that immediately precedes the first user argument. Other rules for marshalling C++ arguments are described in CPPABI.`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042d/IHI0042D_aapcs.pdf)

**EDIT:**

the full implementation of what I am trying to do is here:
http://pastebin.com/6mrUC7td

it works perfectly in visual studio, but I can't get it to work right in XCode/iOS

Answer (score 3):

The [arm abi](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042b/IHI0042B_aapcs.pdf) specifies that the registers `r0` to `r3` are used for parameter passing. The `this` pointer is always in the first register, this would be `r0`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not particularly safe to `call` anything from gcc inline assembler, because there's no way to tell the compiler about it (no *constraint* to gcc inline asm instruction can express "this thing contains a function call, do all that's necessary to save/restore whatever you keep in registers that may change when making a function call").

You can theoretically do that "manually" by giving a clobber list specifying all registers that are *potentially* changed when making a function call as per the platform ABI (quite a lot on ARM, I think it's pretty much all of them excluding `sp` ...). But doing that frequently creates the situation that gcc tells you the constraint cannot be met (i.e. it doesn't have any registers left to stuff "things it needs to preserve" into), depending on the context where your inline asm is used.

Why exactly do you need to call a function from within the inline assembly ? Couldn't you use a `static inline` function instead that combines ordinary C code (which does the function call) with inline assembly to do what can only be done in inline assembly ?

If the *entire* function is inline assembly only, gcc on ARM offers a way out - namely, the `__attribute__((naked))` option. That tells the compiler not to create function prologues / epilogues for it, and you're obligated to write these yourself, i.e. add code that saves/restores registers used by this function but declared preserved by the EABI. By "outsourcing" your inline assembly that does function calls into a `static inline __attribute__((naked))` function, you can get around having to specify extensive clobber lists, as the compiler will recognize it's a function call (and preserve/restore as necessary around it, even when inlining the code).

Comment: I am trying to call the function from assembly because my main goal is to overwrite the stack pointer. So before I do the function call, I need to move anything I want to keep out of the stack, and into a register.

Comment: @al bundy: There's system interfaces for this - `setcontext()` under UN*X (that includes Android/iOS) and `SetThreadContext()` under Windows (that includes WinCE / WinPhone). Manually reimplementing it is only ever necessary if you're writing your own OS.

Comment: actually, it seems that ucontext has been deprecated completed... not sure why it's not supported anywhere.. Windows has fibers, but beside that, there really isn't any support for user level threading. I was trying to put together something that I could use to implement Coroutines/cooperative multitasking, but this sort of thing is turning out to be a little out of my league. Boost recently accepted Boost::Context, but it has yet to see an official release =/ so I guess I'll just have to stick to threads for now.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by deprecated. `struct ucontext` is there in the latest UNIX specs, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/ucontext.h.html - just that the generic spec leaves the interesting part, `mcontext_t`, unspecified / system-specific. You could implement coroutines in UNIX via signals and `sigaltstack()` - slightly lighter-weight than full `setcontext()`. Not sure many still look into cooperative multitasking ... Sun abandoned that from their Solaris libthread back in 2002, native thread performance turned out better, nothing was left to justify the complexity.

Comment: That said ... threads vs. coroutines ... the difference is largely in setup overhead. If you only create threads at the time you want to do the handoff, then it'll definitely be slower than `makecontext()`/`setcontext()` (or their home-grown equivalents). If a thread(pool) for the coroutine(s) already exists, then using semaphore(s) for the triggers and letting the OS do the context switching for you should give the same ballpark figures as coroutines / manual context switches. It's the technique used in this DrDobbs article: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/cross-platform-coroutines-in-c/184404529

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.ethernut.de/en/documents/arm-inline-asm.html). Although it uses x86 assembly, the same works for arm assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing with the stack pointer there - is this an x86 idiom that you don't need on ARM or are you intentionally trying to set up a new stack pointer?

In any case, the stack pointer is in `r13` - the Program counter is `r15` - `LDR` or `MOV` into `PC` effects a branch.   Outside the function prologue, SP already points to the next location on the stack, so you'd only ever need to modify it if you needed to pass arguments on the stack due to the registers `r0-r3` not being sufficient - which is not the case here.

If you do modify the stack pointer, you need to restore it after the function call or you'll get a nice little crash on exit of your function.

Finally, you will need to declare all registers that the ARM [E]ABI allows callees to modify on function call as clobbered.   This is `r0-r3`, `r9` {maybe} and `r12`.

If you're doing this on iOS, ISTR there is subtle variation on register usage.

Comment: I am actually trying to implement coroutines. I am trying to set up a new stack pointer for the function, then longjmp out of the function to restore the original stack. Then I can longjmp back into the function and the new stack will still be there. I am not specifying clobbered registers because I figured that if I am immediately calling the new function, and then doing a longjmp right after it, the contents of those registers would be irrelevant.

Comment: That makes more sense - so, your stack is already allocated in object and the arithmetic get you the pointer for a descending stack - which you hope is large enough!

The list clobbered registers is all of those that the compiler must assume are modified by the end of the `asm` block .  If you're never planning on returning, it really isn't an issue - the presence of a branch and link (`blx`) instruction suggested that you might be.   However, if return is possible, the longjmp will trash the lot!

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution to get the required info for ABI (like in which registers gets what value passed): Just write a couple of lines dummy code where a c++ method is called, and disassemble the result (on your target platform).

Comment: I've actually been trying to do this... but where visual studio will give me a a near perfect translation of my code, xcode generates some very strange assembly.. for example, in vs12, "mov esp, _stack" translates to exactly that, where in xcode "mov %[__stack], %%sp\n\t" translates into around 4 lines.. it seems to be adding some strange offsets before moving it into the register =/